# android camera intent with positive button not functioning

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm trying to use a camera intent, using the code below.

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    return false;
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("user prof", "resultcode: "+resultCode);
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was  taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The camera works, it opens and let me take the photo, but the positive button is not functioning, it doesn't close the intent and doesn't show in the logcat or with Toast tool. The problem is that the method "onActivityResult" is never called when pressing the positive button in the camera intent, in the other hand, it's correctly called when pressing the negative button.

I declared these permissions in the manifest

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

that problem appears because the imageUri I've used is possibly un-readable for the device on which I'm developing, it doesn't give me any error in the logcat, but if I do not set the extra_output, it's perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using these codes`intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);. This code is for video.`

Use below code to capture image.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Yes, EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY flag is a mistake.
I've tried your solution but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you using  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE instead of MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: check this tutorial http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/12/31/android-camera-real-tutorial/